# How to prevent extra yticks within a Tikz Grid?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I created a nice scatter diagram based on the example at http://www.dgsiegel.net/news/2011_12_05-creating_beautiful_graphics_with_pgfplots.

The problem I have now is that in order to show all the *y*-ticks the size of Y has to be increased. Doing this yiels 2 extra *y*-ticks with the last known value. As illustrated in the below image:

[image: Bad y ticks]

The code for this diagram is as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  grid=major,
  point meta=explicit,
  xmin=0,
  xmax=10,
  xlabel=Cijfer,
  scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000*50+50}%
    \let\opacity=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000*7.5+1}%
    \def\markopts{mark=*, color=skyblue1!\opacity,%
    fill=skyblue1!\opacity, mark size=\pgfmathresult}%
    \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
  },
  scatter/@post marker code/.code={\endscope},
  symbolic y coords={
    AlgemeneTevredenheid,
    Toegankelijkheid,
    TelBereikbaarheid,
    BereikbaarheidHelp,
    GebruiksvriendelijkheidHelp,
    Klantvriendelijkheid,
    ProbleemoplossendVermogen,
    Deskundigheid,
    Professionaliteit,
    Terugkoppeling,
    GebodenOplossing,
    ToepasbaarheidOplossing,
    NakomenAfspraken
  },
  xtick = {1,...,10},
  x=0.59cm,
  y=0.8545cm,
]
\addplot[only marks,scatter]
  table[x index=0, y index=1, meta index=2] {CijferDistributie.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Changing `y=0.8545cm` controls the height of each line, decreasing it too much will not show each y-tick, increasing it will add extra lines.

I would like to show each *y*-tick, but not have the extra lines included. Anybody have an idea on this subject?

For completeness, the `CijferDistributie.dat` file looks like this:

```
Cijfer  Vraag   Aantal
1   AlgemeneTevredenheid    0
2   AlgemeneTevredenheid    0
3   AlgemeneTevredenheid    0
```

Arjen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is adding `ytick=data`.  Then you only get lines corresponding to the data entries in the table.  Alternatively you can specify `ymin`, `ymax` and perahps set `enlarge y limits=true`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  grid=major,
  point meta=explicit,
  xmin=0,
  xmax=10,
  xlabel=Cijfer,
  scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000*50+50}%
    \let\opacity=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000*7.5+1}%
    \def\markopts{mark=*, color=blue!\opacity,%
    fill=blue!\opacity, mark size=\pgfmathresult}%
    \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
  },
  scatter/@post marker code/.code={\endscope},
  symbolic y coords={%
    AlgemeneTevredenheid,
    Toegankelijkheid,
    TelBereikbaarheid,
    BereikbaarheidHelp,
    GebruiksvriendelijkheidHelp,
    Klantvriendelijkheid,
    ProbleemoplossendVermogen,
    Deskundigheid,
    Professionaliteit,
    Terugkoppeling,
    GebodenOplossing,
    ToepasbaarheidOplossing,
    NakomenAfspraken%
  },
  xtick = {1,...,10},
  ytick=data,
  x=0.59cm,
  y=0.8cm,
]
\addplot[only marks,scatter]
  table[x index=0, y index=1, meta index=2] {CijferDistributie.dat};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  grid=major,
  point meta=explicit,
  xmin=0,
  xmax=10,
  xlabel=Cijfer,
  scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000*50+50}%
    \let\opacity=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000*7.5+1}%
    \def\markopts{mark=*, color=blue!\opacity,%
    fill=blue!\opacity, mark size=\pgfmathresult}%
    \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
  },
  scatter/@post marker code/.code={\endscope},
  symbolic y coords={%
    AlgemeneTevredenheid,
    Toegankelijkheid,
    TelBereikbaarheid,
    BereikbaarheidHelp,
    GebruiksvriendelijkheidHelp,
    Klantvriendelijkheid,
    ProbleemoplossendVermogen,
    Deskundigheid,
    Professionaliteit,
    Terugkoppeling,
    GebodenOplossing,
    ToepasbaarheidOplossing,
    NakomenAfspraken%
  },
  xtick = {1,...,10},
  ymin=AlgemeneTevredenheid,
  ymax=NakomenAfspraken,
  enlarge y limits=true,
  x=0.59cm,
  y=0.8cm,
]
\addplot[only marks,scatter]
  table[x index=0, y index=1, meta index=2] {CijferDistributie.dat};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```